# Могут ли Ruby блоки храниться в переменных?

Tags: ruby, blocks

Могут ли в Ruby блоки храниться в переменных и являются ли они объектами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непосредственно блоки - нет. Блоки - не объекты. Когда ты используешь метод, который принимает блок, то во время вызова преобразуется в `Proc`.
Подробности [здесь](http://awaxman11.github.io/blog/2013/08/05/what-is-the-difference-between-a-block/)

Но можно использовать `Proc` или лямбду:

```
lambd = -> { p "labda called" }
proc = Proc.new { p "proc called" }
lambd.call #=> "labda called"
proc.call #=> "proc called"
```

Их так же можно использовать чтобы передавать вместо блоков:

```
def blk_caller(&blk)
  blk.call
end

def yield_caller
  yield
end

blk_caller(&lambd) #=> "labda called"
blk_caller(&proc) #=> "proc called"
yield_caller(&lambd) #=> "labda called"
yield_caller(&proc) #=> "proc called"
```

Comment: Пост немного устарел. Proc и lambda -- нынче вроде одно и тоже.

Comment: @Nakilon собственно anoam лишь приводит синтаксис, который актуален. Кроме того, между Proc и lambda по прежнему существуют различия при использовании в них оператора return и в их параметрах.